# PHP Matrix Peek Right, Down, Left, Up In The Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix

I have a 3x3 matrix in `PHP`:

```
2 4 6
5 4 7
8 5 7
```

Assuming I am on the `[0,0]` element so 2. What is the best way to store where I am in the multi-dimensional array in a variable $current? I am thinking pointer, but not sure how to do this in PHP.

```
$current = $data[0][0];
```

Does not help, because it doesn't store context.

Secondly, what the best way to then code looking (peeking) right, down, left, and up assuming $current is stored?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no pointers in PHP, and you wouldn't be able to do pointer arithmetics on references.

You can use the [`next()`](http://php.net/next) and [`prev()`](http://php.net/prev) functions to go forward and backwards in an array and you can use [`key()`](http://php.net/key) to find out where you are. [`current()`](http://php.net/current) will return the value stored at the current position in the array (kind of like dereferencing the pointer).

These all work on a single level of depth, so you can't find the position in a multidimensional array.

The best way of working with multidimensional arrays is likely simply storing and incrementing / decrementing the X and Y values that identify a position in the array. Since arrays in PHP are implemented internally as hashes, referencing `$data[$x][$y]` is very fast, regardless of what `$x` and `$y` contain.

For example, if your current position in the matrix is (1, 1), you could have a variable storing this:

```
$current = ['x' => 1, 'y' => 1];
```

To find out what's stored there, look it up:

```
$x = $current['x'];
$y = $current['y'];
$data[$x][$y];
```

To find out what's stored at the upper-left side of this position, you could obtain the position by simply subtracting 1 from the current position's coordinates, then looking up that position:

```
$x = $current['x'] - 1;
$y = $current['y'] - 1;
$data[$x][$y];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single value as an index, and `value % 3 = row`, `(int)(value / 3) = column` for you. To go up decrease by 3, to go down increase by 3, left decrease by 1, right increase by 1. Also make sure you are always at the boundaries.

Comment: this is the way to go. modular arithmetic works awesome here.

Comment: This is indeed a more elegant solution. It works for square or rectangular matrices, but not for ones where rows or columns can have differing numbers of items. I don't know the OP's problem context, but that probably is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just store your current position as a two-element array?

```
$current = array(0,0)
```

And then you would access the variable at location $current with:

```
$array[$current[0]][$current[1]]
```

If you are iterating over the array -- I assume by using a pair of nested loops -- you would just increment `$current[0]` in the outer loop and increment `$current[1]` in the inner loop (and set it to zero in the outer loop). Note that this stores your "vertical" position in the first element of $current. If you want the order to be (x,y) like standard Cartesian coordinates, just reverse the two elements.